# Mostrar um objeto/variável com nomes diferentes no R?

Tags: r, variáveis, loop, objetos

Considerando a seguinte rotina:

```
x <- 1:10

for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  ## Nome da variável:
  nomevar <- paste0("Var_", i)
  var <- x[i] + 2 
  assign(nomevar, var)
  print(nomevar) # aqui esta minha duvida
}
```

Comment: Como dito na resposta, isto é possível, mas é uma má ideia. Seria muito melhor salvar o valor em um vetor com nomes, uma lista, ou algum outro objeto.

Comment: Vou considerar sua ideia em minhas próximas rotinas. Obrigado @Molx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode substituir a sua última linha pelo seguinte trecho:

```
print(eval(parse(text = nomevar)))
```

A função `parse` transforma a string que é o conteúdo da variável `nomevar` em uma expressão do R. A função `eval` executa a expressão.

```
> x<-1:10
> 
> for (i in 1:length(x)){
+   ## Nome da variável:
+   nomevar<-paste0("Var_",i)
+   var<- x[i] + 2 
+   assign(nomevar,var)
+   print(eval(parse(text = nomevar)))
+ }
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
[1] 11
[1] 12
```

Note que esse uso não é muito comum e nem recomendado. Devem existir melhores maneiras de obter o mesmo resultado provavelmente usando listas ou environments.

---

Veja como eu faria o seu loop usando estruturas mais comuns no R.

```
x<-1:10
results <- list()
for (i in 1:length(x)){
  ## Nome da variável:
  nomevar<-paste0("Var_",i)
  results[[nomevar]]<- x[i] + 2 
  print(results[[nomevar]])
}
```

Comment: Valeu @Daniel. Não sei se este é o melhor caminho ou o mais fácil, apliquei este raciocínio em dois momentos. Primeiro, em um passo intermediário de uma rotina, em que preciso ver os resultados do loop na tela para decidir o que fazer no passo seguinte. Depois de analisar os resultados, chamo os objetos/variável desejados pelo nome dado no loop. Funcionou bem!l!

Comment: Veja o que adicionei na resposta! O sei jeito funciona, mas acredito que usando listas fica mais fácil de programar!!

Comment: @DanielFalbel Seria melhor usar uma lista pré-populada, ou um `lapply`,  ao invés de crescer a lista `results`. Isso pode ser bastante problemático se a lista for grande. (Veja [The R Inferno Circle 2](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf))

Comment: @Molx claro! Aqui era só para manter a mesma estrutura do loop do Jean

Comment: @Molx entendi. Neste caso específico consegui resolver problema. Mas já estou imprimindo o The R Inferno Circle 2 para ler final de semana. Valeu

Answer (score 4):

Você também pode usar a função `get`:

```
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  ## Nome da variável:
  nomevar <- paste0("Var_", i)
  var <- x[i] + 2 
  assign(nomevar, var)
  print(get(nomevar)) 
}
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
[1] 11
[1] 12
```